# Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup MVVM Binding Issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin-community-toolkit

Attempting to utilize Xamarin Community Toolkit Popups in Xamarin Forms MVVM pattern project, target platforms IOS & Android. Popups are appearing, however I cannot bind to display my PopUpMessage string from viewmodel. Here is my code.

XAML:

```
<xct:Popup.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:ProviderApplicationViewModel />
</xct:Popup.BindingContext>

<StackLayout Style="{StaticResource PopupLayout}">
    <Label Style="{StaticResource Title}" 
           Text="Application Status" />
    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource Divider}" />
    <Label Style="{StaticResource Content}" 
           Text="{Binding PopUpMessage}"
           TextColor="Black"/>
    <Button Text="OKAY"
            Style="{StaticResource ConfirmButton}"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class ProviderApplicationPopup : Popup
{
    public ProviderApplicationPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e) => Dismiss(null);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private string popupmessage;
public string PopUpMessage 
{ 
    set { SetProperty(ref popupmessage, value); } 
    get { return popupmessage; }
}
```

ViewModel Popup Navigation:

```
if (response == "True")
{
    PopUpMessage = "Your application has been submitted!";
    Navigation.ShowPopup(new ProviderApplicationPopup());
    IsBusy = false;
    return;
}
```

[Missing Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi4W1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell until I've seen rest of the code though I think the issue is how you are instantiating your `ProviderApplicationPopup`.

First your are setting `PopupMessage` value then you instantiate `ProviderApplicationPopup` but then probably `ProviderApplicationPopup` is also instantiate new ViewModel with null `PopupMessage` value.

So you could pass string directly when instantiating `ProviderApplicationPopup` like
`new ProviderApplicationPopup("Your application has been submitted!")` then set the value in constructor

P.S: Or you can also instantiate ViewModel first then pass that to `ProviderApplicationPopup` and then bind it.

Edit:

```cs
var viewModel = new ProviderApplicationViewModel()
{
    PopUpMessage = "Your application has been submitted!";
}
Navigation.ShowPopup(new ProviderApplicationPopup(viewModel));

//------------- In ProviderApplicationPopup -------------

public ProviderApplicationPopup(ProviderApplicationViewModel viewModel)
{
    BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

Comment: Did the same, works on Android, but not on iOS

Comment: Same for me, it works on android, but not on iOS. any fix ?